# Batch Padding and Shuffling for tf,train.SequenceExample

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've been following few references as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2354 and https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/ to see how we can both perform padding and shuffling within batch. the first link is closer to what I expect but does padding not shuffling within the batch. Individual batches are shuffled but not the batch elements.

in the second link standard tensorflow APIs are used like tf.train.batch which does padding but not shuffling and tf.train.suffle_batch which does shuffling but not padding.

is there any other approach to perform both padding and shuffling with in the batch

Comment: In case you need this for RNN, keep in mind that dynamic_rnn allows unequal-length sequences as input, for which you have to specify the sequence length parameter. This should do the padding for you (so in case you don't find the answer on how to combine the batch and shuffle_batch functionalities).

Comment: do you have any reference that says dynamic_rnn should do the padding based on sequence lengths ..

Comment: I will post a few URLs into an answer below, because they won't fit in this comment field...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `dynamic_rnn` that you were asking in the comment, check the docs here:
[dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)

The parameter you need to specify is `sequence_length=[]`, which is `None` by default. You are meant to pass a vector of as many sequences as you have in each call to `dynamic_rnn`, where each vector element is a number that represents the number of steps of each sequence. I think ultimately it should make them all equal length and pad with zeros, but the point is to avoid updating the state over the empty steps.

I never had to do this myself, but have seen various examples arounds, so you might want to search around. One example is here:[Variable Length Sequences](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html). Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for your response.  Calling dynamic_rnn with a sequence_length parameter returns padded outputs. However what I'm asking is on the input side where I would like to perform padding and shuffling within a batch. currently, I'm performing these actions thru the python way which is working good. however, i would like to make use of SequenceExample for which I could not find a unified approach for doing shuffling and padding. hope my concern is understood